# Why does CoreData's fetchDataForEntity also fetch Child-Entities?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have defined two `NSManagedObject` Entities.

```
FTEvent : NSManagedObject
```

[image]

and

```
FTFeed : FTEvent
```

[image]

When I fetch only `FTEvent` surprisingly I get also all `FTFeed` entities.

```
NSManagedObjectModel *model;

- (NSMutableArray*)fetchDataForEntity:(NSString *)entityName
{
    //Get ALL of a kind of entity from the store
    NSArray *result;
    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *rec = [[model entitiesByName] objectForKey:entityName];
    [request setEntity:rec];

    result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!result)
        [NSException raise:@"Fetch Failed" format:@"Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
    return [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result];
}

NSMutableArray allEvents = [self fetchDataForEntity:@"FTEvent"];  // ????
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the sub entities, you can set the  `includeSubentities` property to `NO` on the `NSFetchRequest`

Comment: I was just about to throw away my changes and start from scratch, until I saw your answer. This is a great solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely by design: in Core Data, parent-child means the same thing as *inheritance* in Objective C. When you set `FTEvent` as a *parent entity* of `FTFeed`, you tell Core Data that each `FTFeed` is an `FTEvent`. Hence, when you ask for all `FTEvent` objects, all "child" (i.e. "subclass") `FTFeed` objects are returned as well.

This terminology is confusing to people familiar with database terminology, where parent-child means *composition*. See "Entity Inheritance" section of the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html).

Comment: Indeed, I didn't expect this behaviour. Many thanks for clarifying it. Flexicoders solution means, I can continue with my existing solution though.

Comment: @Hooman I am not sure that you can continue with your existing solution without reworking it to fit the parent-child structure that you are building. If in your model a feed is an event, then you can use your structure; if in your model an even *has* one or more feeds, you would be forced to change it.